# Why does the image size change after save?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a problem in size of image size (M*N)
when i read an image as np.array after i apply an algorithm method ,the size of its change to another value.some time increase and some times decrease depend on image.

```
img = cv2.imread('baboon.jpg',1)  # read image (255*255)
na = np.array(img)  # convert it to array
x, y ,pp = img.shape[:3]  # size of 3d
blue = np.array(range(x*y), int).reshape((x, y))
blue[:,:] = na[:, :, 0]
en_split_block_8(red,31,1)  # function algorithm
```

**I use this code to save the image and the size changes from (255*255) to (640*480)**

```
plt.imshow(blue,interpolation='nearest',cmap="gray")
plt.savefig('blue.jpg')#(640*480)
```

I want the image to keep it's size. (I don't change size of image just i work on values).

[image: original image]

[image: image after encryption and save]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are saving the image with `pyplot` which shows the image as a diagram. What you want to do instead is save the `blue` image using `cv2` with: `cv2.imwrite('blue.jpg', blue)`.

Beware that `na = np.array(img)` is redundant as to why `img` is already an `ndarray`.